# ¿Como aplicar funciones en un array con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5

Supongamos que tenemos la siguiente función en javascript:

```
var modal=$("div[class*=div_modal]");
//Accedo al primer elemento del array
var modal2 = modal[0];
//quiero obtener el primer div
modal2.children('div').eq(0);
console.log(modal2);
```

Pero me da el siguiente error:

```
modal2.children is not a function
```

por que ocurre esto? como le aplico el children ?

Comment: `modal[0]` es un [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) no un selector de jQuery. Por lo tanto no tiene sus métodos.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaratoria amenadiel, pero podria aplicarle de alguna manera un foreach para aplicarle algun metodo de jquery? No se convertirlo o algo asi?

Comment: `var modal2 = modal.eq(0);` funciona. Mira la respuesta que te pusieron abajo. También `var modal2 = modal.first();` Y con eso `modal2.children('div').each(...)` hace exactamente lo que quieres.

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que tienes un HTML similar al ejemplo que doy mas abajo y que estas usando jQuery, yo procedería de la siguiente manera:

```js
var modal = $("div.div_modal");
var modal2 = modal.eq(0);
console.log(modal2);

// Y para obtener el contenido
console.log(modal2.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
   <div class="div_modal">1</div>
   <div class="div_modal">2</div>
   <div class="div_modal">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Buena respuesta Francis, ahora la cosa es que quisiera usar el array que genera esta variable: var modal = $("div.div_modal");  ya que es un formulario diamico del cual tomara estos valores, no sera estativo. Por pregunto lo del array.

Comment: Tienes alguna idea con array?

Comment: Puedes hacer algo como 

modal.each(function(key, child) {
  var modalChild = $(child);
  console.log(modalChild.html());
  
});

Donde estarias haciendo un foreach de cada elemento del array, y ahi puedes ejecutar la logica que desees

Answer (score 1):

Como te escribió en un comentario @amenadiel, ese es un objeto `HTML` el cual no tiene los métodos de `jQuery` y si es posible hacer que tengan sus métodos, solo tendrías que hacer algo como esto:

```
//Tú código
var modal=$("div[class*=div_modal]"),
      //Usamos el selector de jQuery para poder usar sus métodos
      modal2 = $(modal[0]).children('div').eq(0);

console.log(modal2);
```

No sé mucho de `jQuery` y la verdad no me agrada usarla, pero solo tienes que seleccionar el `HTMLElement` para poder usar sus métodos.

Espero y te sirva.